# Python/Gunicorn ssl handshake failure

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, gunicorn

I am running Ubuntu, Python 3.6, Gunicorn + Flask with an SSL cert. I occasionally get an error message about an invalid SSL request.

```
[2020-08-28 13:48:33 -0400] [6347] [DEBUG] Error processing SSL request.
[2020-08-28 13:48:33 -0400] [6347] [DEBUG] Invalid request from ip=x.xx.xx.xx: [SSL: SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl handshake failure (_ssl.c:2309)
[2020-08-28 13:48:33 -0400] [6347] [DEBUG] Failed to send error message.
```

I believe it may have to do with the disk, as it is a pretty severe bottleneck on this machine. Maybe it's unable to read the cert in time because of disk?

I set up Gunicorn with a standard SSL setup:

```py
keyfile = 'keys/x.key'
certfile = 'keys/x.pem'
ca_certs = 'keys/x2.pem'
```

Comment: Please give more details on how you configured SSL.

Comment: Added details. I didn't really "configure" it aside from setting the location of the certs for gunicorn.

Comment: Seeing the same error. Let me know if I can provide details of my setup, if it can help.

Comment: i am having same error, and i dont see where is the problem exacrtly!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is old, but for those who lands here like me: **GO CHECK YOU "JWT_SECRET_KEY" IS BEING READ CORRECTLY**

Comment: How? Can you provide more detail on what a developer should do to verify that? Without that information, I'm not sure this will prove especially useful to future developers encountering this issue.

Comment: well @JeremyCaney , this depends on how the developer is reading the security key, so we cannot be very specific. For me it was something like this `app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = str(os.environ.get('TOKEN'))` but Python (gunicorn) was not able to find the environment variable